# Select Query missing the required result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the data to re-create the scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE PAT (
    NAME VARCHAR(500),
    REFNO INT
);

CREATE TABLE MEDICATION (
    REFNO INT,
    MEDICA INT
);

CREATE TABLE PERSONAL (
    REFNO INT,
    PNNAME INT
);

INSERT INTO PAT VALUES ('MANOJ', 100)
INSERT INTO PAT VALUES ('SURESH', 101)

INSERT INTO MEDICATION VALUES (100, 1)
INSERT INTO MEDICATION VALUES (100, 2)
INSERT INTO MEDICATION VALUES (101, 3)
INSERT INTO MEDICATION VALUES (101, 1)
INSERT INTO MEDICATION VALUES (101, 5)

INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (100, 10)
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (100, 11)
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (100, 13)
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (101, 10)
INSERT INTO PERSONAL VALUES (101, 15)
```

Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]

What I have tried using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT NAME,PAT.REFNO,MEDICA,PNNAME FROM PAT 
FULL JOIN (SELECT MEDICATION.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (REFNO) ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SEQNUM FROM MEDICATION) AS METABLE ON METABLE.REFNO = PAT.REFNO
FULL JOIN (SELECT PERSONAL.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (REFNO) ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SEQNUM FROM PERSONAL) AS PERSONALTABLE ON PERSONALTABLE.REFNO = PAT.REFNO AND PERSONALTABLE.SEQNUM = METABLE.SEQNUM
```

This gives me this output:

[image: My Output]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want is suppression of data and ordering of result

use `CASE` expression to check for the `SEQNUM` and display the `NAME` & `REFNO` accordingly

---

```
SELECT  NAME    = CASE WHEN COALESCE(METABLE.SEQNUM, PERSONALTABLE.SEQNUM) =  1 
                       THEN PAT.NAME END, 
        REFNO   = CASE WHEN COALESCE(METABLE.SEQNUM, PERSONALTABLE.SEQNUM) =  1 
                       THEN PAT.REFNO END, 
        MEDICA, PNNAME
FROM    PAT 
        FULL JOIN 
        (   
            SELECT  MEDICATION.*, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (REFNO) 
                                           ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SEQNUM 
            FROM    MEDICATION
        ) AS METABLE        ON  METABLE.REFNO = PAT.REFNO
        FULL JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  PERSONAL.*, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (REFNO) 
                                           ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SEQNUM 
            FROM    PERSONAL
        ) AS PERSONALTABLE  ON  PERSONALTABLE.REFNO  = PAT.REFNO 
                           AND  PERSONALTABLE.SEQNUM = METABLE.SEQNUM
ORDER BY COALESCE(PAT.REFNO, METABLE.REFNO, PERSONALTABLE.REFNO),
         COALESCE(METABLE.SEQNUM, PERSONALTABLE.SEQNUM)
```

Comment: using ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) is a risky kludge - logically that tells the database engine to order them anyway it wants. It is not deterministic. It "might" match your goal and it might not - depending on runtime factors. That important detail should have been mentioned and stressed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` expressions for the columns `NAME` and `REFNO`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN pt.SEQNUM = 1 THEN p.NAME END AS NAME, 
       CASE WHEN pt.SEQNUM = 1 THEN p.REFNO END AS REFNO, 
       m.MEDICA, 
       pt.PNNAME 
FROM PAT p 
FULL JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REFNO ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SEQNUM FROM MEDICATION) AS m 
ON m.REFNO = p.REFNO
FULL JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REFNO ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SEQNUM FROM PERSONAL) AS pt 
ON pt.REFNO = p.REFNO AND pt.SEQNUM = m.SEQNUM
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=600332cc311ce9535f5a722d6b7059f2).

Comment: The  13 value of PNNAME column is different the SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO. https://imgur.com/a/IwfScqn

Comment: @ManishKumar I have only your sample data to test and for this sample data I get your expected output. Can you reproduce your result in the fiddle?

Comment: [@forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498828/forpas) I'm convinced that its working on Fiddle, but the main problem is behavior of that row. Do you think of any reason for that behavior in IDE?

Comment: using `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` is a risky kludge - logically that tells the database engine to order them anyway it wants. It is not deterministic. It "might" match your goal and it might not - depending on runtime factors. That important detail should have been mentioned and stressed.